# Google geocoding api not working in android phones while it is working in system with Ripple in Apache Cordova

Tags: android, json, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've developed a test app for a weather finder based on zip / pin codes.
Unfortunately, I couldn't get the json resultset on android mobiles while working with the google geocoding api. And it is working fine on my system, when tested with Ripple mobile simulator. I've used the following api for finding out the latitude and longitude based on the zip / pin code of the location.

[Link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50001&sensor=true)

Please suggest me a suitable api from which I could get the latitude and longitude in Json format from the pin code of certain area.

Here is the code I've written to render the weather based on the zip/pin code.

```js
function getWeather() {
    var zipcode = $('#input-box').val();

    var qs = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zipcode + "&sensor=true";

    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';

    $.getJSON(qs, function (results) {
        lat = results.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lng = results.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

        var queryString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lng + "&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0";

        $.getJSON(queryString, function (res, status) {
            $('#temp').text(res.main.temp - 273.15);
            $('#description').text(res.weather[0].description + " in " + res.name);
        });
    });
}
```

FYI, there are two api calls (google geocoding api and open weather api) I've made in the above script and control is not even entering into the getJSON.

Here is the console list when viewed on source.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65zaY.png)

Comment: This is how I've framed the query string to get the latitude and longitude from the zip/pin code.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50001&sensor=true

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). I think you have to allow your app to request external URLs.

Go to your project root folder and install the plugin:

```
cordova plugins install cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Afterwards put this into your `config.xml` between the android platform tag:

```
<platform name="android">
  <!-- Don't block any requests -->
  <access origin="*" />

  <!-- other stuff -->
</platform>
```

Don't forget to rebuild your target:

```
cordova build android
```

Comment: Hello Beat. Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it is not working still. I've made necessary changes as you said and rebuild the application.

Its working on my system and not on my android mobile.

Comment: Yes. There are few errors.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ ripple.js:50
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)

Comment: Hi Beat, I'm adding the screenshot in the question.

Comment: But your issue is on the device, what about those errors?

Comment: I've seen those errors in the ripple simulator. And there were no errors on the actual device. The control is not even entering the $getJSON(...) function where I tried to change the text of the heading to check the result.

Comment: Then your problem belongs to another part of your code i guess

Comment: Is there any other way of debugging the code for any errors in mobiles, just in case if it is returning null or some other kind of errors in the call back function!?

Comment: Do you use **remote debugging** with your device?